# Create an associative array with integer keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I need to create an associative array in javascript with an `integer` key as follows;

```
a["10"] = "ten";
```

but when i create an array, it puts the value to the `10th` index of the array and it creates an array with the length 11. I want it to be a key value pair. I know this can be done by using objects but i need an array only.

Comment: arrays were not meant to do this, so why do you need an array? Perhaps objects have the functionality you are looking for, but you just aren't aware.

Comment: i am using javascript with a project in SAPUI5, and i need arrays to populate in the dropdowns and the dropdowns does not support the objects. i need arrays only.. :(

Comment: Javascript arrays **are** Objects. The "indexes" are just numeric property names, the length property is defined as being the highest index plus one, it is not a count of the indexes.

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays. The only way to do this in JavaScript is to use objects:

```
var a = {
    '10': 'ten'
};
```

Comment: but i need to have only the array. isn't there any workaround for this??

Comment: -1 JavaScript *does* have [Associative Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (aka Map aka Dictionary); albeit in a limited form (i.e. Objects) *that coerce all keys to strings*. While the term feels fairly antiquated, it is valid and is commonplace some languages like Perl (and is abused in other languages like PHP).

Comment: @Daksh - Nope. Can you tell us *why* you need it to be an array? Maybe we can work around *that*.

Comment: @pst - The limited form you are talking about is exactly what I presented here. It has similar functionality to an associative array, but it's *not* an array.

Comment: @Daksh - there is no such thing as a sparse/associative array in javascript.  You can have an array or an object.  Those are your choices.  You can want something different, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: @pst at the risk of going a bit meta, unless I misunderstand your comment, I think it's pedantic and not constructive, and that a downvote was not necessary.

Comment: @Cam I disagree. This answer starts with an incorrect statement.(Also, it does not explain why using `"10"` in as an Array property is identical as using `10`, so there is nothing to counter-balance my nit.)

Comment: @pst: I stand corrected - the point you made was reasonable even if I don't entirely agree with it, so it's neither pedantic nor nonconstructive. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @pst - ECMAScript 6 *does* have maps (which are even more similar to associative arrays), but that would *still* not be an array. An array in JavaScript is an object constructed from the Array constructor, and which - consequently - has access to its prototype methods. No amount of hand flailing will ever change that.

Comment: @JosephSilber "In computer science, an *associative array, map, or dictionary* is an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key, value) pairs, such that each possible key appears at most once in the collection." - The ADT imposes no requirement on Ordering or Complexity. Also, 1) this answer, without an explanation of how indexer into Arrays are "special", doesn't really say much and 2) It is possible to create a new Object that uses Array.prototype.

Comment: @pst I think it's fair to say that JavaScript does not have associative arrays in the sense that the op is asking. he specifically states that he needs an array,  not an object, which I take to mean a data structure that type-identifies as a capital-A Array.

Comment: @pst - Which again, is pedantic. The OP obviously wants an array so they can use it in JavaScript in the same manner as they would use other arrays, in which case  the official abstract data type definition won't do them much good.

Comment: @joseph : i am using javascript with a project in SAPUI5, and i need arrays to populate in the dropdowns and the dropdowns does not support the objects. i need arrays only.. :(

Comment: @jfriend00—I think the term "sparse" is OK and understood as an array where some indexes are elided, e.g. `[0,1,,,4]` or are otherwise undefined.

Comment: @RobG - but a javascript array is not sparse in terms of the length of the array which it seems the OP is asking about and a plain object has no length so neither choice fits what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript *does* have [Associated Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)<sup>1</sup> - Objects (and by extension, Arrays) are an example

*However*, **[some properties of Arrays are treated specially](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4)**:

> *Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names.* A property name `P` (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to `P` ..
>
> .. *Specifically, whenever a property is added whose name is an array index, the length property is changed, if necessary,* to be one more than the numeric value of that array index ..

Thus, given `arr = []`, the expressions `arr["1"]` and `arr[1]` refer to the *same property* name. Since `P` (the property name) is "1" and `length` is 0 from above, then assignment to such property will set `arr.length` to `ToUint32(P)+1`, or 2.

It is *not* possible to change this behavior. If you wish to *not* have a special `length` property, then use a "normal" Object instead of an Array. However, many of the `Array.prototype` functions *can* be used with arbitrary objects (with some implementation quirks aside) that have a `length` property and an Object *can* be created such that it uses `Array.prototype` as its own prototype.

All that being said, the post *does not say what the real issue is*. Instead of supposing that it must be done in that particular manner, consider explaining what the intent is: e.g. why a["10"]? And what is wrong if there are "11 items" if the object will be used in a List?

---

<sup>1</sup> Please read the article before debating this statement: the term "Array" in the name does not imply an ordered sequence nor does it preclude an *additional* notion of a Length or the use of Hashing, etc. If you are going by a *different* definition, make sure to specify what it is and what the desired behavior is for a given operation.