# Syntax for creating an array with a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, key

Edit: total simplification.

Consider this code:

```
let arr = [42,69]
arr.key = 'lol'
```

It creates a key value to an array.

However, is it possible to write those two lines in one? I can't find a syntax that works and I'm not sure it is possible.

The reason I want this is because I push the array into another array.
I could use an object, but I plan to pop items from it later and it doesn't work on objects.

```
let all = []
all.push({'0':42,'1':69,'key':'lol'})
```

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ - it's helpful to expand on this. It doesn't appear to be valid syntax, you're mixing up arrays and objects, so presumably you mean it throws an error. But more broadly we've no idea what your inputs are or what output you're expecting. Give a [mre].

Comment: You can't add keys to arrays. You can make an object `{key : val}` or store the key in the item in the array - again with an object `myarray = [{name: "item", key: 500},{name:"item 2", key:501}]`

Comment: Apparently it is called associative arrays. And I can add keys to it if I do it on the next line.
`pickedrocks[0].key = 500` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @agiopnl Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @Unmitigated, well initially I had only the Rock-objects. I needed to send temporary information with them, so I didn't want to add it inside the class.

Comment: To clear up confusion, _associative arrays_ don't exist in JS and arrays in JS aren't actually arrays in the traditional definition but objects that have some "magic" syntax and behaviors that make them look like arrays. That's why you can add your "key" property to an array after you created it. You basically end up with an object that looks something like this: `{ "0": 567, "1": 37, "key": "lol", "length": 2 }`. If you have a need to set custom, non-numeric keys, it's more appropriate to use a plain object than an array.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "it doesn't work" means invalid syntax. The title says it's a syntax problem, and a minimal reproducible example seems overkill for a syntax problem. Anyways I rewrote the post to simplyfy things. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @Lennholm thank for the info. Yeah, I know that everything is an object on some level, I just call it an array when it has square brackets. I tried arr.push([{'0':captureBin.rocks.pop(),'key':500}]) it seem to work the same way, however the square brackets in the console changed also. Do you think that might just be the console interpretation from the code? Btw: A couple of guys in this thread says that JS has associative arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313444/create-an-associative-array-with-integer-keys

Comment: @Lennholm I did some more testing, and you are wrong about ending up with an object that looks like that. I think you are only faking an array because of the obj[key] syntax looks the same as arr[0] .Yes, all arrays are objects, `typeof arr` returns 'object' even if it is created using the Array()-constructor. The difference between your object and my array is that the array still has .length and the array-functions .pop(), .map() etc., the object does not.

Comment: @agiopnl I am not wrong. The array functions are inherited from `Array.prototype`, they are not part of the object itself. I just didn't mention the object's prototype because it wasn't relevant to the point I was making, namely that arrays are objects.  There's nothing special about the fact that arrays have this particular prototype. All objects have prototypes. A plain object has `Object.prototype` and you can give an object any prototype you want. Create a plain object, set its prototype to `Array.prototype` and you'll have all those array functions on your plain object.

Comment: @Lennholm Ok, how do I do that? `obj.prototype = Array.prototype`? Anyway I can't do that inside a .push()

Comment: @agiopnl I don't suggest you do that because it only makes things complex but you can use `Object.create(Array.prototype)`. To get back to you issue though, there's no literal syntax that creates an object with custom keys that is also an array because they're intended for different use cases. I think your approach should be to rethink your design a bit. If you need a custom key in addition to the array, make it an object that has the array as one of its members. Something like this: `pickedRocks.push({ list: arr, key: 'lol' })`

Comment: @Lennholm I was just gonna test if the prototype-idea really worked. How do I use `Object.create(Array.prototype)`? Thanks, but the array is really a class-object and I plan to .pop() it later and it doesn't work with objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240337/discussion-between-agiopnl-and-lennholm).

Answer (score 0):

In js you can't have keys in arrays. They only support the index. If you want to assign keys you have to use objects or use the index to do so.

For example like so

```
const pickedRocks = []

// with objects
pickedRocks.push({value: lastBin.rocks.pop(),key: 500})

// with array index: 0 = value, 1 = key
pickedRocks.push([value: lastBin.rocks.pop(),500])
```

However since you have a key you could use an object instead of an array alltogether. Unless you want to be able to have duplicates.

```
const pickedRocks = {}

pickedRocks[500] = lastBin.rocks.pop();
```

Comment: I didn't think I could either, but

`pickedrocks[0].key = 500`

works perfectly fine.

In the console it looks like this:

pickedRocks[0]
[Rock, fromX: 894.0303571428572, fromY: 966.6660714285714, toX: 1483.5446428571427, toY: 730.9696428571428]
0: Rock {x: 112.46964285714286, y: 87.46964285714286, color: 'hsl(35,540%,60%)'}
fromX: 894.0303571428572
fromY: 966.6660714285714
toX: 1483.5446428571427
toY: 730.9696428571428
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: An array is just an object, you _can_ add other arbitrary properties to it. But the [_array literal syntax_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) doesn't support arbitrary properties. You could do it with e.g. `Object.assign`, but it's unclear from what you've posted whether that makes sense at all in your context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is my understanding as well. There are no asociative arrays in js. Here we use Objects or Sets

Comment: @VincentMenzel Btw: A couple of guys in this thread says that JS has associative arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313444/create-an-associative-array-with-integer-keys

Comment: @agiopnl They are talking about objects. Notice they are defined like so `{ ... }` while an array is defined like this `[ ... ]`. The objects ALWAYS requires key - value pairs `{ someKey: 'someValue' }`. Values can also be set later using the variable `myObject['someKey'] = 'someOtherValue'` or using dot notation `myObject.someKey = 'someOtherValue'`

Comment: @VincentMenzel I know, I didn't think arrays could have keys either, try the code `let arr = [42,69];
arr.key = 'lol'; arr;` it creates something that looks like an array and has keys, I just figure this must be an associative array.

Comment: When I tried it it created the array with 2 entries however the key value pair `key: 'lol'` wasn't persisted

Comment: @VincentMenzel what do you mean? It's accessible in all my three browsers and also in node.